# If any student have spouse name populated, then automatically mark them as married = true

Tags: apex, force.com, validation-rule

am new to salesforce,and i wrote Validation rule for if spouse name populated,married field value true automatically.

```
 AND(ISBLANK( Spouse_Name__c ), Married__c  = True )
```

please suggest me to achieve this functionality....

Comment: Marking someone as married automatically, seems like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a validation rule to set a value, you can use it to throw an error if the value is not as you expected.  The below will throw an error if the Spouse_Name__c field is blank, and the Married__c field is not true

```
AND(
     NOT(ISBLANK(Spouse_Name__c)),
     Married__c = False
)
```

If you wanted to set the value of Married__c to true automatically, you could use a Workflow or the Process Builder for that.

Comment: He could also create a checkbox formula field "Is married" that it's true if NOT(ISBLANK(Spouse_name__c)) So you don't have to depend on a boolean field that has to be updated all the time based on that criteria.

Comment: ^ Very True, that's an option as well.